# onSuggestionClick recreates my activity

Tags: android, searchview

In my application i made my content provider searchable, defining my main activity as the default search activity on my manifest.

```
    <activity
            android:name="com.pt.application.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
```

Then i implemented the onSuggestionClick option to update a map, based on the suggestion clicked by the user. The searchview is on the action bar.
The problem is that when the user clicks on a suggestion, somehow the activity is recreated (i think OnPause and OnResume are called?). Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I don't want that my activity is "recreated" every time the user clicks on a suggestion.

If more code is needed, please ask. Thanks.

**EDIT: Code added**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:voiceLanguageModel="web_search"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.pt.provider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.pt.provider/busstop">
</searchable>
```

On my main activity:

```
        // Bind the Activity’s SearchableInfo to the Search View
            searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
            this.setupSearchView();

    private void setupSearchView()
        {   
            // Use the Search Manager to find the SearchableInfo related
            // to this Activity.
            SearchManager searchManager =
                    (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            SearchableInfo searchableInfo =
                    searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName());
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo);
            searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(false);

            searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new OnSuggestionListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {

                    // Do things

                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please add your activity code (or at least all relevant parts that have to do with search) as well as your searchable.xml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my question. Changed on the manifest:

From:

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

To:

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Comment: You can also return true from onSuggestionClick(), that way Android will assume that your method handled the click event and won't do anything else about it (e.g. start your activity again) - it's probably a "cleaner" way to do it (and the "officially recommended" one), even though your method works as well.